# How to calibrate / reset the MFD (touch screen) on 2007 Toyota Prius

Tags: toyota, electronics, prius, navigation

I just bought a used 2007 Prius.

**Its MFD (touch screen) is miscalibrated such that I need to touch 1 or 2 centimeters above what I actually want to press.** For on-screen menu options shown near the top of the screen, this is obviously impossible. So I desperately need to calibrate the system.

[Please watch this short video of me attempting to get to the Calibration screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYqLYPGKPqo&feature=youtu.be) of my 2007 Prius.

I've tried the steps published at [2007 Prius - Easter Egg](http://andrew.daviel.org/prius/egg.html), but it didn't seem to work for me; I can get into System Check Mode but can never reach the Product Diagnosis Menu or the Calibration page.

(Is there a hardware way to reset the screen? Or if I plugged in an OBD2 cable, could I instruct the system that way?)

If you have a suggestion, I'd LOVE to hear it!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you holding "Info" or "Display" while flicking your lights?

Comment: Also, the instructions say "parking lights," I hear 2 clicks in your video, which suggests "headlights." Try just going to the 1st click.

Comment: @tlhIngan Thank you for your suggestions. I've tried Info and Display, and I've tried parking lights and headlights.

Comment: Just bumping this. Any resolution yet? I have this problem too.

Comment: @Dan Unfortunately I'm worse off than before: I dismantled my dash to try to unplug the MFD to see if that could reset it. It did not. And in the process, the weak plastic of the dashboard broke in many places.  Now my car looks terrible, and the MFD still isn't calibrated. I'll never buy a Toyota again.

Comment: Someone online told me that he was able to recalibrate his MFD by using strong magnets. The strongest magnets I own didn't have any effect for me, though.

Comment: so, i can enter the diagnostic screen just fine, did you press the power button without your foot on the brake, make sure the engine is not actually started, hold INFO while flicking the headlights on and off five times, this has always worked for me edit: nevermind, i see the problem, you just cannot activate the top menu button, because there is some calibration within that menu that i saw